# linker error on the llvm gcc compiler for the simulator only

Tags: ios6, ios-simulator, llvm, llvm-gcc

We are in the process of moving our project from LLVM GCC to Apple LLVM. One of the libraries we have is built only for arm and not i386. This is causing issues where we get the warning on the simulator build after which we not end up linking anymore. This worked fine in GCC as I was able to compile the app just fine. This warning is harmless for us on the simulator. Is there any way to ignore the warning as it was on LLVM GCC.

I looked at the project build settings as well to figure out if there was a flag that I could use to switch off this warning.

I have looked enough stack overflow questions similar to this one. Most of them suggest to get both the flavors (arm and i386) of the binary and combine them. I still wonder how this worked in LLVM GCC and why there was no compilation error.

Any ideas ?

the warning that I get, 
ld: warning: ignoring file library.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

thanks